# Webpack production version

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possibile to figure out in config file what version of file will be created?

I have simple config file:

```
...
entry: {
      "./src/application.js": "./dev",
      "./src/application.min.js": "./dev"
},
module: {
   loaders: [{
        test: /application\.js/,
        loaders: ["uglify"]
      }]
},
output: {
    path: './',
    filename: "[name]"
}
...
```

If I run `webpack` it should be run only `./src/application.js` and if I run `webpack -p` it should be run both (or only uglify version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this was help full:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
    isProduction = process.argv.indexOf("-p") > -1,
    plugins = [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].gz.css")
    ];

if(isProduction){
    plugins.push(new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "{file}",
        regexp: /\.js$|\.css$/
    }));
}
```

and in `module.exports` change `plugins` to `plugins: plugins`